# digit Nth powers in a given limit

Tags: java, loops

Can any one tell me where i had gone wrong

[image]

so far i tried these i passed 3 test cases it failed in one case i am providing link to problem where i encountered [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler030) is the link this is a problem in hackerrank the site to improve coding skills

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
 Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = z.nextInt();
for (int i = 2; i < Math.pow(10,n)-1; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    int number = i;
    while (number > 0) {
        int d = number % 10;
        number /= 10;

        int temp = d;
        for(int j = 1; j < n; j++){
            temp *= d;
        }
        sum += temp;
    }

    if (sum == i) {
        result += i;
    }
}
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it fail or time out?

Comment: it failed second test case but passed remaing 3 test cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm assumes that the number of digits in an acceptable solution is less than or equal to the input (power), but that is not always true.  If n = 5, then you miss the 194,979 solution as 194,979 > 10^5-1  So, you have to increase the upper bound of the numbers you are testing.

My math skills are failing me as I don't know what the exact upper bound should be, but this seems to work (changing Math.pow(10, n) to Math.Pow(10, n+1)):

```
for (int i = 2; i < Math.pow(10,n+1)-1; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your maths, mostly on loop delimiters, e.g. `for(int j = 1; j < n; j++)` looks suspect, especially when you have `Math.pow(number%10,n)`.

This seems to woprk - I've also pre-calculated all of the digit powers to streamline.

```
private static final int MinDigits = 4;
private static final int MaxDigits = 6;
// Pre-calculate powers of digits.
static final int[][] powers = new int[MaxDigits + 1][10];

static {
    for (int d = MinDigits; d <= MaxDigits; d++) {
        powers[d] = powers(d);
    }
}

/**
 * All digits raised to that power.
 */
private static int[] powers(int n) {
    int[] powers = new int[10];
    for (int d = 0; d < powers.length; d++) {
        powers[d] = (int) Math.pow(d, n);
    }
    return powers;
}

private int sumOfPowersOfDigits(int x, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += powers[n][x % 10];
        x /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

private int sumOfMatchingPowersOfDigits(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    // Start at 1000... and work up to 10000....
    for (int x = (int) Math.pow(10, n - 1); x < (int) Math.pow(10, n); x++) {
        // Work it out.
        int sumOfPowersOfDigits = sumOfPowersOfDigits(x, n);
        if (sumOfPowersOfDigits == x) {
            // Found one!
            System.out.println("Found " + x);
            sum += sumOfPowersOfDigits;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

public void test() {
    for (int i = MinDigits; i <= MaxDigits; i++) {
        System.out.println("Sum of " + i + "th powers = " + sumOfMatchingPowersOfDigits(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

'n' is the size of the number (ie. number of digits in the number and not something that you are trying to enter.) So, if the number is 123456, the question asks if (1^6 + 2^6 + 3^6 + 4^6 + 5^6 + 6^6) is equal to 123456.

The for loop that you are providing, misses this point. What you should be doing is calculating the number of digits in the given number and then apply the logic of the while loop - only in this case, all the power should be the number of digits that wou calculated earlier.

Probable convert the number to String and get the length which would give you the total number of digits in the number in one line if space and time complexity is not something that you are worried of.

Comment: In 10 power of n  sum of those numbers those share property i described in question